# Change smooch avatar from Gravatar

Tags: smooch, supportkit

I'm trying to change the avatar shown on my smooch chat http://docs.smooch.io/ios/#configuring-agent-images
The docs say you simply make a gravatar account.

Is the email you use to sign into smooch to manage settings the same as the `app maker's email address`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the email you use to sign into smooch to manage settings the same as the app maker's email address?

Not exactly. A team of app makers can reply from a variety of channels such as Slack and Zendesk in which case Smooch collects an email address from any of those those 3rd party account emails.

If the email we resolve matches that of the app maker's Smooch account, then the avatar they have configured in Smooch will be used. If you don't have a custom avatar configured in Smooch, gravatar is used as a fallback.

If however the 3rd party account email does not match the Smooch account, then any gravatar configured for that email will be used.

Note that you can also override the all outgoing messages, under Messaging Options you can set `Use app icon and a single team name for all messages`.